# Bind click event to container, but exclude element within container from event logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:blue;">
    <!-- Other markup -->
    <button type="button">Special Button</button>
</div>

(function ($) {
    $("div").click(function () {
        alert('fired');
        // Don't fire when the button is clicking!
    });
}(jQuery));
```

How can I architect the code/html to *not* fire the "div" click binding when the button is clicked?  Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwC9G/) to play around with.

Comment: in this case use `disabled` at button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prevent event propagation from the button

```
$('div button').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LZ9Wj/)